# Struts2 jquery plugin grid: when selecting a row, call action and hide rows in grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, struts2-jquery

I have the following situation:
in a jsp I show a grid using `<sjg:grid`
among other parameters I use

- `hidegrid=true` to allow to hide/show all rows in grid, and
- `id=gridInfo`
- `onSelectRowTopics="rowGetInfo"` to call a script.

when a row is clicked, `rowGetInfo` is activated and calls an action which in the end must call a new jsp and display data below the grid (I haven't coded this part, might be another grid for example).
All this part is working fine, also thanks to suggestions read in here.
What I want to do now is:
in the script `rowGetInfo`, I would like to be able to hide the grid rows, similarly to what happens when the `hidegrid` button is clicked.
this is the script as I have written it:

```
$.subscribe('rowGetInfo', function(event, data) {
    $("#variabile").val(event.originalEvent.id);
    var grid = event.originalEvent.grid;
    var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    var variabile = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'variabile');  
    $("#resultSelect").show().fadeIn("slow");
    $("#gridInfo").jqGrid('setGridParam',{gridstate:'hidden'});
    $("#resultSelect").load("myaction"+"?variabile="+variabile);
});
```

using `gridstate:hidden` has no effect. I also tried `$("#gridInfo").hide`, which worked but did not allow me to show again rows when clicking on the `hidegrid` button
Any idea?

Comment: Did my answer help you to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the following should hide the grid in the same manner as the hidegrid button.

```
$('#gridName').jqGrid('setGridState', 'hidden')
```